# Why does Mongoose virtual methods for 'id' return string instead of ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js project that uses Mongoose v5. In the process of upgrading to v6 of Mongoose, I discovered that my virtual properties switched from returning an ObjectId to returning a string.

Edit: On further review, I discovered this is not true for *all* virtuals, but it is true for a virtual named 'id'.

Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
// user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
});

userSchema.virtual('id').get(function() {
  return this._id;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
//index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('./user');

async function main() {
  let dbUrl = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost/assess?authSource=admin&directConnection=true';
  await mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
  let user = await new UserModel({ name: 'Jim' });
  console.log(`in Mongoose v${mongoose.version}, user.id has type ${user.id.constructor.name}`);
  await mongoose.disconnect();
}

main();
```

Notice the schema maps the _id property to the id property via a virtual property.

Here's the relevant output for each Mongoose version:

```
$ npm i mongoose@5
$ node index.js
in Mongoose v5.13.17, user.id has type ObjectID

$ npm i mongoose@6
$ node index.js
in Mongoose v6.11.2, user.id has type String

$ npm i mongoose@7
$ node index.js
in Mongoose v7.2.4, user.id has type String
```

I need this virtual property to return an ObjectId, not a string. Obviously, the property is returning an object of type ObjectId but somehow between the return from the function and the receipt of the return value, it's getting transmuted into a string in versions 6 and 7 of Mongoose.

How do I prevent this transmutation?